# Hetzner's installimage script, RAID1 hard drives + SSD

Tags: lvm, partition, software-raid, ssd, hetzner

I just purchased a server from Hetzner, with two 4TB hard drives and one 1TB SSD. I want to setup the two hard drives (/dev/sda & /dev/sdb) in RAID1 and install the OS on them, and have the SSD (/dev/sdc) as an extra drive.

Until now, all my tentatives failed. The installimage script runs fine, and tells me that I just need to reboot. But when I reboot, I have this error:

[image]

I tried fixing the error without luck and gave up, as I suspect that the problem comes from my installimage script config.

Here's the configs I used for all my tries:

```
DRIVE1 /dev/sda
DRIVE2 /dev/sdb
#DRIVE3 /dev/sdc # commented to exclude it from the RAID setup
SWRAID 1
SWRAIDLEVEL 1
BOOTLOADER grub
HOSTNAME EX51
```

And here are the different partitioning schemes I tried:

1°) Nearly the default config

```
PART  swap   swap   32G
PART  /boot  ext3   512M
PART  /      ext4   all
```

2°) A try with LVM

```
PART  /boot  ext3   512M
PART  lvm    vg0    all

LV  vg0  swap  swap  swap  4G
LV  vg0  root  /     ext4  all
```

3°) Partitions smaller than 2TB in case that the system does not use grub2 (is it?)

```
PART  swap   swap   32G
PART  /boot  ext3   512M
PART  /      ext4   1T
PART  /p1    ext4   1T
PART  /p2    ext4   1T
PART  /p3    ext4   all
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT: disabling RAID works.

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: Yep sorry, I forgot I asked that question! I posted the solution I found, hopefully it will help you!

Comment: I want to do the inverse. Have my ssd be the system partition and raid 0 the hdds only. So I guess I just comment out the other drivers and install with swraid disabled, then I do it after installation

Comment: Yes I'd do the same: comment the HDDs, and setup your RAID after the installation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I finally got it working. I don't remember exactly what went wrong, but here's what I'm doing now:

1°) Use the following config (the `/autoconfig` file):

```
DRIVE1 /dev/sda
DRIVE2 /dev/sdb
#DRIVE3 /dev/sdc
SWRAID 1
SWRAIDLEVEL 1
BOOTLOADER grub
HOSTNAME EX61
PART  swap     swap   32G
PART  /boot     ext3    512M
PART  /            ext4    all
IMAGE /root/images/Ubuntu-2204-jammy-arm64-base.tar.gz
```

For other sample configs see the `configs` folder in Hetzner's [`installimage`](https://github.com/hetzneronline/installimage/tree/master/configs) GitHub repo.

2°) Once `installimage` script has finished, but **before rebooting**, create mount folder & update fstab:

Create the mount folder:

```
mkdir /mountFolder
```

Update fstab:

```
cat > /etc/fstab
```

Paste:

```
proc            /proc    proc  defaults  0 0
/dev/md/0  none     swap  sw        0 0
/dev/md/1  /boot    ext3  defaults  0 0
/dev/md/3  /            ext4  defaults  0 0
/dev/sdc1  /mountFolder   ext4  defaults  0 0
```

Then reboot.

3°) If the /dev/md2 error occurs, format the SSD:

```
parted /dev/sdc mklabel gpt
parted /dev/sdc print unit MB print free
```

Note the size of the disk for the next command

```
parted --align optimal /dev/sdc mkpart primary ext4 0% 960197MB // replace the size here
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc1
```

Check if fstab needs to be updated again, if so do it:

```
cat /etc/fstab
```

(paste the same as in step 2)

Finally create the mount folder and mount the drive:

```
mkdir /mountFolder
mount -a
```

Comment: This answer is great - I've added some clarifications in my own answer that should help point out some additional steps that may now need to be take as I believe the installimage has been updated since this answer was written.

Answer (score 7):

[Tim Autin's](https://serverfault.com/users/475942/tim-autin) answer is brilliant (particularly if like me you don't have access to the console and cannot see the boot messages), but I'm going to add some additional bits as I think the installimage has changed slighly since his original answer - or I was simply too tired when following it to realise some of the probably obvious points I've highlighted below.

1) Follow Tim's step 1

2) In Tim's step 2 be aware that the current root file system is the installimage file system, not the servers file system, so you need to mount that first.

```
mkdir /rootPartition
mount /dev/md2 /rootPartition
```

3) Now complete Tim's step 2, but be aware that any reference to /etc/fstab should be changed to /rootPartition/etc/fstab

4) Reboot - but this probably won't work.

5) If it doesn't reboot then boot back into the Rescue Image (via the Hetzer Robot, mount the root partition (see this answers Step 2 above) and then follow Tim's step 3, remembering to prefix any reference to files (such as /etc/fstab) with /rootPartition.

6) Reboot. This time it should work (it did for me).

Big thanks to Tim for solving this - hope these additions help others.

Comment: Glad I helped! Thanks to you for adding this, if I go through this again (and I hope I won't...) I'll try to update my answer.

Comment: Two years old, but thank you to both you and @TimAutin. Only note is that my drives were named a bit differently with the large extra drive being `/dev/sda` so if anyone finds this, make sure you check your own infrastructure and not just a raw copy/paste.